# visual studio 2010: how to auto replace concrete types with interface

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I read the book `How to work with legacy code`

It said that in many IDEs there is an option to automatically

- extract an interface from a class
- replace classes members from concrete to the new interface

I have found the first option in VS2010, does anyone know how to do the second?

Comment: A very low-tech option, if nothing else works; rename `ConcreteClass` to something else - then fix the compiler errors (updating to the interface). Then repair `ConcreteClass`. The inbuilt rename function may do this more cleanly - i.e. rename `ConcreteClass` using the IDE to `ITheInterface`, which should fix all existing references - then manually change it back to a class (without using the rename function).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think out of the box.
First rename your class

- `MyClass` to `IMyClass` and tell VS to rename references
- rename it back to `MyClass` and don't rename references
- extract interface to `IMyClass`

Comment: You are my hero

Answer (score 0):

use Resharper a visual studio add on. It costs but you can get a free trial for 30days I think. Its very good and can do what you mentioned.

Comment: Click in the menu resharper > refactor > extract interface and then extract interface.

Comment: it does only the first requirement, not the second